# how to sum two array elements in assembly?

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio, assembly, x86

(assembly code using visual studio syntax) I know it's an obvious question but I'm new to assembly.

I'm having problems to understand how does `esi` register work in an exercise like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *c;

    c = &b[0];

    __asm {
        mov ebx, c 
        mov eax, dword ptr [ebx]
        mov esi, 3
        add eax, dword ptr [ebx+esi*4]
        mov ecx, eax
        mov a, ecx 
    }

    printf("sum of first and fourth element is: %d", a);
}
```

I need to print sum of first and fourth element. The program works as follows:

- define `a` and the array `b`, define pointer `c`, and it points to the first element of `b`.
- move `c` in `ebx`. [`c` points to the first element, and therefore `ebx` contains the first element]
- move the things to which pointer points to into `eax` register. [it's `ebx`]
- move `3` into `esi` register. [critical part I didn't understand]
- add operator [critical part I didn't understand]
- move operators [easy part, no problems]

my questions are:

- why do I have to copy `3` into `esi` register?
- why do I have to do this operations? `[ebx+esi*4]`

I know `esi` makes things a lot easier, but I don't understand how to use this register.

Comment: *"Why do I have to copy `3` into `esi` register?"* Because you will add `b[3]`. *"Why do I have to do this operations? `[ebx+esi*4]`?"* Because `4` is `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane could you explain it better? and I guess I have to sum ebx because it's like a counter, right? it's like c when I had to increment a variable in a loop

Comment: @WeatherVane what does bx stand for?

Comment: why didn't you put "e"?

Comment: Register `ebx` holds the address of the base of array `b[]`. To index element `b[3]` you must add the offset `3 * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: What does bx stand for? Sorry I had corrected that typo. Please refresh the page.

Comment: And why is it `3`? Beacuse in an array, that is the index of the **fourth** element as described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the first and fourth elements of array `b` is written:

```
int a = b[0] + b[3];
```

Since pointer `c` is initialized to point to the first element of `b`, this is equivalent to

```
int a = c[0] + c[3];
```

To add `c[3]` with `ebx` containing the value of `c`, the code sets `esi` to `3` and uses `add eax, dword ptr [ebx+esi*4]`. This instruction adds a 32-bit value read from the memory int the array pointed to by `ebx` at index `esi`, multiplied by the size of `int` directly as part of the addressing mode.

This would be useful and efficient if `esi` contained the result of some computation or the value of an argument, but for a constant index, a simpler way is to compute the offset at compile time:

```
add eax, dword ptr [ebx+12]
```

Also note that using `ecx` to store the result is redundant too.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *c = b;

    __asm {
        mov ebx, c
        mov eax, dword ptr [ebx]
        add eax, dword ptr [ebx+12]
        mov a, eax
    }

    printf("sum of first and fourth element is: %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that it is unclear whether the assembly code can have side effects on `ebx` and `esi` without consequences...

Comment: MSVC inline `asm{}` blocks can modify any register you want (except EBP or I think ESP).  It parses your asm to infer a clobber list.  (That's why you can't use `db` to manually encode instructions, but it still has to know about all instructions with implicit output operands like `mul`.)  The actual implementation is apparently pretty brittle and clunky, since it's documented as not safe to use asm blocks in functions with any register args. *[What is the difference between 'asm', '\_\_asm' and '\_\_asm\_\_'?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/59576185)*

Comment: And the actual doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/using-and-preserving-registers-in-inline-assembly?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170 .   (Unlike GNU C inline asm where as long as you specify the operands and clobber list correctly, the calling convention of the function you put it in is irrelevant.)

Comment: You could `lea edx, b` I think, which will compile to `lea edx, [ebp + constant]`.  You don't need to invent a pointer variable which the C stores to memory for you to reload.  Or perhaps even `mov eax, b[0]`, IDK.  Fortunately MSVC inline asm is pretty much obsolete.